# talib ADX function error

Tags: python, ta-lib

Using python pandas dataframe (d) downloaded from yahoo finance which has the format:

Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2015-01-13,1.290,1.290,1.200,1.225,421600,1.225

I can successfully use talib functions like this:

```
talib.abstract.EMA(d, timeperiod=8, price='Close')
talib.abstract.SMA(d, timeperiod=13, price='Close')
talib.abstract.RSI(d, timeperiod=25, price='Close')
```

From the documentation (http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func_groups/momentum_indicators.html) they take the form:

```
real = XYZ(close, timeperiod=14)
```

However when trying to use the talib functions with the form:

```
real = XYZ(high, low, close, timeperiod=14) such as the ADX I cant figure out the correct syntax needed.
```

I've tried this:

```
talib.abstract.ADX(d,high='High',low='Low',close='Close',Timeperiod=10)
```

Exception: input_arrays parameter missing required data keys: high, low, close

and this:

```
talib.abstract.ADX(high=d.High,low=d.Low,close=d.Close,Timeperiod=10)

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Any ideas on the correct format for the parameters needed for this and the other talib python wrappers that have more than one input parameter ?

Any help on the correct format would be greatly appreciated !!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the shape of your arrays in some cases. If you really need the function as a matter of urgency, just call it from the library:

```
import talib
import numpy as np
h = np.array(high)
l = np.array(low)
c = np.array(close)
output_atr = np.array(talib.ATR(h,l,c,14))
```

This works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. FYI talib.abstract works with other functions but failed like this: talib.abstract.ADX(d.High.values,d.Low.values,d.Close.values,10)
But this works:                    talib.ADX(d.High.values,d.Low.values,d.Close.values,10).... so thanks ajsp for the pointing me in the correct direction.